# How to Switch input on an X-Fi Titanium from line to mic?

Tags: 10.04, sound, microphone

The X-Fi Titanium has a single input for mic or line level input. Right now it's set to line level. On Windows, there would be a checkbox to toggle this, but the sound panel in Ubuntu 10.04 does not seem to have this option. How can I set it to mic level?